# What updates /var/cache/ubuntu-advantage-tools/ubuntu-advantage-status.cache?

Tags: motd, canonical-livepatch, ubuntu-advantage

After logging into 18.04.1 LTS, `motd` shows (among other things):

```
- Livepatch server check failed.
```

Digging into `motd` I see that this message is generated by a script residing in

```
/etc/update-motd.d/80-livepatch
```

and this script is referencing:

```
/var/cache/ubuntu-advantage-tools/ubuntu-advantage-status.cache
```

which contains:

```
esm: disabled (not available)
fips: disabled (not available)
livepatch: enabled
  client-version: 8.0.6
  architecture: x86_64
  cpu-model: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU         661  @ 3.33GHz
  last-check: 2018-11-09T05:00:22.613601172-05:00
  boot-time: 2018-11-09T05:29:20-05:00
  uptime: 18h38m26s
  status:
  - kernel: 4.15.0-38.41-generic
    running: true
    livepatch:
      checkState: check-failed
      patchState: nothing-to-apply
      version: ""
      fixes: ""
```

So it looks like this cache file was last updated yesterday with the output of `canonical-livepatch status` but I am wondering what triggers the update of this file and if there is a way to force it to update?

Note: I do know why livepatch was disabled and it is now enabled again...I still get the failed message when logging in and that is what triggered my quest to understand what is going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/cron.daily/ubuntu-advantage-tools` runs effectively:

```
/usr/bin/ubuntu-advantage status > /usr/bin/ubuntu-advantage/ubuntu-advantage-status.cache
```

Comment: What does `ubuntu-advantage-tools` do, btw ?